# Store functions in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have public holidays stored in an array

```
    $holiday["Christi Himmelfahrt"]       = strtotime("+39 day",easter_date($year));
    $holiday["Pfingstmontag"]             = strtotime("+50 day",easter_date($year));
    $holiday["Fronleichnam"]              = strtotime("+60 day",easter_date($year));
```

and some more...

I was thinking about storing them in a table, because I want to add more countries. Is this a good idea?
I was thinking to store it like this:

```
        Schema::create('holidays', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('calculation');
        $table->string('country',2)->default('AT');
        $table->foreign('country')->references('iso_code')->on('countries');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But how would I get this calculated dates?
And again: is this a good idea at all?

Comment: I just found https://github.com/checkdomain/Holiday -- this will work for me. But it would also be good to know how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need both, the actual date it resolves to and the algorithm used to calculate it. You can have calculated days in a
`holiday` table like:

| id | holiday_type_id | holiday_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 102 | 2 | 2022-11-27 |

... together with a `holiday_type` table that contains the definitions:

| id | country_id | name | month | day | expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | New Year | 1 | 1 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 123 | Lorem Ipsum | *NULL* | *NULL* | last thursday of november |

The expression would be a string that's parseable by `strtotime()` / `new \DateTime()`. The [syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) is quite powerful so you won't possibly need additional information. You can then create a function to make the actual calculations and invoke for every row you need (either in a cron job or with a manual script):

```
public function calculateForYear(int $year): \DateTime
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding another column after_days where you save "39" for example and after you query the database you can do this

```
$holiday = Holiday::select('after_days')->where('id, '=', $id)->first();
strtotime("+".$holiday->after_days." day", easter_date($year));
```

Assuming that the year is static and you don't need to save it in database.

Comment: Why should I store it like this? The way that I store the calculations is working. I can access it like `Holiday::find(1)->calculation`

Comment: What data do you store in the calculation ?

Comment: `strtotime("+50 day",easter_date($year))`

Comment: Not sure if you can call that dynamically, I'd save only the days in calculation or in another column like after_days then you can do and it will work
$after_days = Holiday::find(1)->calculation;
strtotime("+".$after_days." day",easter_date($year))

Comment: @ChrisL I have updated my code in the answer give it a try

Comment: Yes, I am also not sure about it :D There are also some public holidays on fixed dates. Eg new years day: I store the calculation using `mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year)` So theres no "after-days"

Comment: You can easily handle that, let me know if that worked.